# /admin/* pages "The website encountered an unexpected error"

Tags: 8

After two clean installs of Drupal 8.0.2 without issues on my server (Debian 7.1 / PHP 5.6.17 / MySQL 5.5.31) I can log in and out fine and view my user profile page, but that's it.

Any /admin/* pages returns the following error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

I'm a little stuck as effectively I can't do anything and this wasn't an issue locally on WAMP. Can someone offer me guidance please? I've had a look for error logs on the server but unless I'm looking in the wrong places I'm not seeing anything.

Database watchdog shows the following error. (The serialized array has been edited to show the relevant parts.)

> GuzzleHttp requires cURL, the allow_url_fopen ini setting, or a custom HTTP handler.
>   GuzzleHttp\choose_handler()
>   /var/www/virtual/mysite.info/drupaltest/htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php";
>   line 116

As suggested in other similar posts I have tried increasing `max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) I'm afraid we can't help to debug your site from here without more info, but it should be easy enough to get at the real error - check the `variables` column in the watchdog table, it'll have the replacements for `@message`, `%function`, `%line` and `%file`. Once you've got those edit them into the question and it'll be a lot easier to point you in the right direction

Comment: No worries - you're just missing cURL, `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` and a web server restart ought to fix it

Comment: Thanks so much dude! You should post this as an answer so I can give you your dues ;)

Comment: @MatthewECornish I think Clive has enough points as it is. You can post the answer yourself and thank him there ☺.

Comment: make sure your `$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;` in your settings and try pointing your browser to: example.com/core/rebuild.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get this marked off as answered (with thanks to Clive).

First of all was understanding how to make use of the database watchdog table to find the errors. You have to download and view the variables column... the error's in there. In my case it was that cURL was not installed.

It was as simple as installing cURL and restarting the Apache service.

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```

Thanks again to Clive!